# CS50 pset3 Tideman Exercise Cannot Compile

Tags: c, cs50

I have no idea why my code could not compile. Need some help/advise! Attached below is my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Max number of candidates
#define MAX 9

// preferences[i][j] is number of voters who prefer i over j
int preferences[MAX][MAX];

// locked[i][j] means i is locked in over j
bool locked[MAX][MAX];

// Each pair has a winner, loser
typedef struct
{
    int winner;
    int loser;
}
pair;

// Array of candidates
string candidates[MAX];
pair pairs[MAX * (MAX - 1) / 2];  //no. of pairs= n(n-1)/2
int pair_count;
int candidate_count;

// Function prototypes
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[]);
void record_preferences(int ranks[]);
void add_pairs(void);
void sort_pairs(void);
void lock_pairs(void);
void print_winner(void);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
// Check for invalid usage
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: tideman [candidate ...]\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Populate array of candidates
    candidate_count = argc - 1;
    if (candidate_count > MAX)
    {
        printf("Maximum number of candidates is %i\n", MAX);
        return 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        candidates[i] = argv[i + 1];
    }

    // Clear graph of locked in pairs
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            locked[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    pair_count = 0;
    int voter_count = get_int("Number of voters: ");

    // Query for votes
    for (int i = 0; i < voter_count; i++)
    {
        // ranks[i] is voter's ith preference
        int ranks[candidate_count];

        // Query for each rank
        for (int j = 0; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            string name = get_string("Rank %i: ", j + 1);

            if (!vote(j, name, ranks))
            {
                printf("Invalid vote.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }

        record_preferences(ranks);

        printf("\n");
    }

    add_pairs();
    sort_pairs();
    lock_pairs();
    print_winner();
    return 0;
}

// Update ranks given a new vote
bool vote(int rank, string name, int ranks[])
{
    // TODO

    for(int i=0; i < candidate_count; i++ )
    {
        if(strcmp(candidates[i],name)==0)
        {
            ranks[rank]=i;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Update preferences given one voter's ranks
void record_preferences(int ranks[])
{
    // TODO

    for(int i=0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            preferences[ranks[i]][ranks[j]]++;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Record pairs of candidates where one is preferred over the other
void add_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO

    for(int i=0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1; j < candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if (preferences[i][j] < preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner= j;
                pairs[pair_count].loser= i;
                pair_count++;
            }

            else if (preferences[i][j]> preferences[j][i])
            {
                pairs[pair_count].winner= i;
                pairs[pair_count].loser= j;
                pair_count++;
            }

        }
    }
    return;
}

// Sort pairs in decreasing order by strength of victory
void sort_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO

    for(int i = pair_count-1; i >=0; i--)  // This nested loop is for bubble sort. Need i loop so that ith pair can start comparing. i.e after the 1st pair is done comparing with the rest of the pairs, the 2nd pair starts comparing with all other pairs so on&so forth)
    {                                      // Need start i from decreasing count so that each new pair will compare with lesser number of pairs as the pairs at the back has already been compared previously.
        for(int j=0; j <= i-1; j++)        // j loop is to compare ith pair with all other j pair.
        {
            if((preferences[pairs[j].winner][pairs[j].loser]-preferences[pairs[j].loser][pairs[j].winner]) < (preferences[pairs[j+1].winner][pairs[j+1].loser]-preferences[pairs[j+1].loser][pairs[j+1].winner]))
            {
                pair temp= pairs[j];
                pairs[j]= pairs[j+1];
                pairs[j+1]= temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

bool hascycle (int winner, int loser)
{
    for(int i=0; i < candidate_count; i++)
    {
        bool found= false;
        while(winner!=loser && winner!= -1)
        {
        if(locked[i][winner])
        {
            winner= i;
            found= true;
        }
        if(!found)
        winner= -1;
        }

        if(winner==loser)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
}


// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO

    for(int i=0; i < pair_count; i++)
    {
        if(!hascycle(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser))
        locked(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser)= true;
    }
    return;
}

// Print the winner of the election
void print_winner(void)
{
    // TODO

    for(int i=0; i< candidate_count; i++)

    {
        int false_count=0;

        for(j=0; j<candidate_count; j++)
        {
            if(locked[j][i]==false)
            {
                false_count++;

                if(false_count==candidate_count)
                {
                    printf("%s\n", candidates[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return;
}
```

**Warnings:**

```
:) tideman.c exists
:( tideman compiles
    code failed to compile
:| vote returns true when given name of candidate
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| vote returns false when given name of invalid candidate
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| vote correctly sets rank for first preference
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| vote correctly sets rank for all preferences
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| record_preferences correctly sets preferences for first voter
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| record_preferences correctly sets preferences for all voters
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| add_pairs generates correct pair count when no ties
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| add_pairs generates correct pair count when ties exist
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| add_pairs fills pairs array with winning pairs
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| add_pairs does not fill pairs array with losing pairs
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| sort_pairs sorts pairs of candidates by margin of victory
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| lock_pairs locks all pairs when no cycles
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| print_winner prints winner of election when one candidate wins over all others
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
:| print_winner prints winner of election when some pairs are tied
    can't check until a frown turns upside down
```

Comment: `code failed to compile` isn't helpful. Do you get the actual compiler error? If so, post it here.

Comment: In the function `hascycle`, the number of `{` and `}` is mismatched. You forgot to close one `{` with a `}`.

Comment: The line `locked(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser)= true;` does not make sense. Do you maybe mean `locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;`?

Comment: Hi @AndreasWenzel Thanks! I realised that too! Have changed it. But there are still some errors. Any idea how to rectify these?

:( lock_pairs locks all pairs when no cycles
    lock_pairs did not lock all pairs
:( lock_pairs skips final pair if it creates cycle
    lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs
:( lock_pairs skips middle pair if it creates a cycle
    lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs

Comment: hi @JohnnyMopp. Its ok. I managed to resolve the compiling issue. I realised I forgot to type "make tideman". I am able to compile now.

But have errors regarding lock_pairs as mentioned. Would be great if you are able to identify what is wrong :)

Comment: @TSH: Have you tried running your code line-by-line in a debugger while monitoring the values of all variables, in order to determine in which line your program stops behaving as intended? If you did not try this, then you may want to read this: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471) You may also want to read this: [How to debug small programs?](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @TSH: Note that CS50 has its own debugger, called [debug50](https://video.cs50.io/v_luodP_mfE?screen=J0ND72qsI9U&start=1688&end=2012).

Answer (score 2):

These are 3 issues that prevent your code from compiling:

1. `hashcycle()` missing a `}`
2. `print_winner()` the variable `j` is not declared:

```
for(int j=0; j<candidate_count; j++)
```

3. `locked(pairs[i].winner, pairs[i].loser)= true;` first part is a function call but you probably want an array assignment:

```
locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
```